# gtest installed with conan: undefined reference to `testing::internal::GetBoolAssertionFailureMessage`

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, conan

I use [cmake](https://cmake.org/) to build my project and [conan](https://www.conan.io/) to install [Google Test](https://github.com/google/googletest) as dependency:

**conanfile.txt**

```
[requires]
gtest/1.7.0@lasote/stable

[generators]
cmake

[imports]
bin, *.dll -> ./build/bin
lib, *.dylib* -> ./build/bin
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
PROJECT(MyTestingExample)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

INCLUDE(conanbuildinfo.cmake)
CONAN_BASIC_SETUP()

ADD_EXECUTABLE(my_test test/my_test.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(my_test ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

**test/my_test.cpp**

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <string>

TEST(MyTest, foobar) {
    std::string foo("foobar");
    std::string bar("foobar");
    ASSERT_STREQ(foo.c_str(), bar.c_str()); // working
    EXPECT_FALSE(false); // error
}
```

**Build**

```
$ conan install --build=missing
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake .. && cmake --build .
```

I can use `ASSERT_STREQ`, but if I use `EXPECT_FALSE` I get an unexpected error:

```
my_test.cpp:(.text+0x1e1): undefined reference to `testing::internal::GetBoolAssertionFailureMessage[abi:cxx11](testing::AssertionResult const&, char const*, char const*, char const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What's wrong with my configuration?

Comment: In which OS and compiler (with version) are you running? The ``conaninfo.txt`` and ``CONAN_LIBS`` content might be useful too.

Comment: It could be a ``libcxx`` mismatch, from the error output it seems that you should be using ``libcxx=libstdc++11``. If in linux (in general, not multi-configuration envs), you should use ``cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release``, assuming that the conan install used the default setting ``-s build_type=Release``

Comment: Thank you very much, `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` fixes this issue.

Comment: Good! Adding it as an answer then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you are installing conan dependencies using the default settings (which is build type **Release**):

```
$ conan install --build=missing
# equivalent to
$ conan install -s build_type=Release ... --build=missing
```

The default settings can be seen in your `conan.conf` file

Then, you are using cmake in a nix system with the default build type which is **Debug**, which is a single-conf environment (opposed to multi-configuration Debug/Release environments, as Visual Studio), so when you are doing:

```
$ cmake .. && cmake --build .
# equivalent to
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug && cmake --build .
```

The incompatibility of Debug/Release build leads to that unresolved issue. So the solution would be to use the same build type that matches your installed dependencies:

```
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release && cmake --build .
```

If using multi-configuration environments like Visual Studio, the correct way would be:

```
$ cmake .. && cmake --build . --config Release
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it also works for me for the particular example of @maiermic but using different asserts still shows undefined reference to me (eg. `ASSERT_TRUE("hi" == "hallo");)`. Did you also tried different assert types?

Comment: This is weird, one assertion working but not the other. Maybe deserves its own question with detailed output and files, or maybe submitting issue to the package author repo: https://github.com/lasote/conan-gtest (if it is the package you are using)

Comment: I started a follow up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162014/gtest-installed-with-conan-undefined-reference and also opened an issue on the repo of lasote https://github.com/lasote/conan-gtest/issues/20

Comment: This helped me to narrow down the issue, thanks.  Another option is to change `build_type=Debug` in `~/.conan/profiles/default`; you may need to completely wipe the `data` folder and your `build` directory too.

Answer (score 1):

On my side, I get this issue because being on Redhat 7 then with an old libstdc++.
Too old for conan default packages binaries/libraries.

I have fixed that by rebuilding gtest with '--build gtest' arg.