# How can I solve undefined reference errors with Conan and SDL2 on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, conan

I am trying to get [conan](https://www.conan.io/) working in a test project by following [their Geting Started guide](https://conanio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) so that I can begin using it in a real project. I am attempting to use SDL2 with glew in a C++ project compiled with g++ on Ubuntu 16.10 x64.

My conanfile.txt looks like this:

```
[requires]
SDL2/2.0.5@lasote/stable
glew/2.0.0@coding3d/stable

[generators]
cmake
```

My CMakeLists.txt file looks like this:

```
project(conantest)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include(conan/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

set(SRC_FILES main.cpp Display.cpp)
add_executable(conantest ${SRC_FILES})
```

My project consists of a directory containing CMakeLists.txt, conanfile.txt, all of my source code, a build directory for Cmake, a conan directory for Conan, and a rebuild.sh. I am using this rebuild.sh script to clean and build the project whenever I make a change to the build environment (the rm -r's, although suboptimal once it is working are there to ensure any errors from the previous setup are removed once I attempt a fix).

My rebuild.sh looks like this:

```
rm -r ./build/*
rm -r ./conan/*
cd conan
conan install ..
cd ../build
cmake ..
make
```

When I run this script, everything seems to be working until the 
final executable is linked. When this happens, I get `` Display.cpp:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `SDL_Init' ``. To solve this, I have tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408216/gtest-installed-with-conan-undefined-reference-to-testinginternalgetboolas) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162014/gtest-installed-with-conan-undefined-reference). Although these are not specific to SDL, I was unable to find any resources that are.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-UppQCCDga3S29zQ2JIR3RRRms/view?usp=sharing) is a zip file of the full environment that I am using, including a MCVE.

Comment: To those who are downvoting: why and how should I improve the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell CMake to link against the libraries yourself, since `conanbuildinfo.cmake` cannot know the name of your target.

Simply adding this line to the bottom of your `CMakeLists.txt` file will work:

```
conan_target_link_libraries(conantest)
```

This command will call [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/target_link_libraries.html) for all dependencies specified in the conanfile.

Here's another `CMakeLists.txt` example if you would like to use a more "modern" CMake approach which focuses more on targets instead of global settings:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(conantest)

include(conan/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup(TARGETS)

add_executable(conantest main.cpp Display.cpp)
set_property(TARGET conantest PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
target_link_libraries(conantest CONAN_PKG::SDL2 CONAN_PKG::glew)
```

Comment: You could also call explicitly the target_link_libraries:

``target_link_libraries(conantest ${CONAN_LIBS})``